# RECESS change properties' order

Tags: css, recess

I use node.js, grunt and RECESS  to compile my *.less files into *.css files.
    It's my Gruntfile.js file

```
 module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    recess: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                compile: true
            },
            files: {
                'css/style.css': 'less/style.less'
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        recess: {
            files: ['less/*.less'],
            tasks: ['recess'],
            options: {
                spawn: false,
            },
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-recess');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['recess', 'watch']);

};
```

but now I need to change properties' order in output *.css file like

```
.class {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  width: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 0;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 0;

  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: none;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;

  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: 1;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: 1;
  white-space: normal;
  word-spacing: normal;

  font: 1em sans-serif;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;

  opacity: 1;
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #fff url(../i/bg.png) no-repeat 0 0;  

  z-index: 0
  cursor: default;
```

}

I've found out `strict-property-order.js` https://github.com/twitter/recess/blob/master/lib/lint/strict-property-order.js#L36 and I guess it can help me, but I don't know how to use it?

Comment: The point of recess is that it's an opinionated way of ordering your css properties. If you want grunt tasks that let you choose an order there are plenty out there (css-comb etc). However if you want to change the order you should just be able to reorder the 'order' array in strict-property-order.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the order in which you wish your properties to be outputted, edit the `order` array in `strict-property-order.js`.

For example:

`order = [
      'position'
    , 'top'
    , 'right'
    , 'bottom'
    , 'left'
]`

could be changed to:

`order = [
      'position'
    , 'right'
    , 'top'
    , 'bottom'
    , 'left'
]`

However, the reason why there is not simply a `config.json`, or something like that, which you can put in the root of your project and edit without having to mess with the node module is because recess is opinionated in the way properties are ordered.

If you want more freedom there are other options out there (such as various .less linters and things like css-comb which can be run after compile).